# Linear Algebra determinant reduction

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove, without expanding, that
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a  &a^2-bc \\ 
1 &b  &b^2-ca \\ 
1 &c  &c^2-ab 
\end{vmatrix} vanishes.

Any hints ?

Comment: what do you mean with "without expanding"?

Comment: not trying to explicitly calculate the determinant (Laplace's expansion)

Comment: You can give a nontrivial linear combination of the columns (or rows) that equals $0$ to show that it vanishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2-bc \\ 
    1 & b & b^2-ca \\ 
    1 & c & c^2-ab 
  \end{vmatrix}
&=\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & a    & a^2-bc        \\ 
    0 & b-a  & b^2-a^2+bc-ca \\ 
    0 & c-b  & c^2-b^2+ca-ab 
  \end{vmatrix} \\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
    b-a & b^2-a^2+bc-ca \\ 
    c-b & c^2-b^2+ca-ab 
  \end{vmatrix} \\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
    b-a & (b-a)(b+a+c) \\ 
    c-b & (c-b)(c+b+a) 
  \end{vmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: This is very nice to my honest opinion, the only thing is that the OP is not allowed to use the laplace expansion, but it is enough to leave the first row and column that you correctly canceled because it contained the column $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What does "OP" mean... ? I have seen this elsewhere as well !

Comment: @user148176 the OP is you! the Original Poster

Comment: @user148176 Also means 'Original Post' - i.e. the thing or the person behind it, obvious from context. (And it's hard to imagine that the difference even matters, other than for correct grammar).

Comment: @Ale "We have met the OP and he is us." -Walt Kelly

Answer (score 6):

Let

$$f(a)=\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a  &a^2-bc \\ 
1 &b  &b^2-ca \\ 
1 &c  &c^2-ab 
\end{vmatrix}$$
then it's easy to see that $f$ is a polynomial on $a$ with degree at most $2$ and $f(b)=f(c)=0$ so
$$f(a)=\lambda(a-b)(a-c)$$
now, WLOG assume that $bc\ne0$, take $a=0$; we see easily that $f(0)=0$ hence $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Why is $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Smooth! Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. if your matrix is $A$, consider $(b-c,c-a,a-b) A$

Answer (score 1):

Add $(ab+bc+ca)$ times the first column to the last and find the common factor of the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a multiple of the first column to the last
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a^2-bc\\1&b&b^2-ac\\1&c&c^2-ab\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a^2-bc+(1)(ab+ac+bc)\\1&b&b^2-ac+(1)(ab+ac+bc)\\1&c&c^2-ab+(1)(ab+ac+bc)\end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a(a+b+c)\\1&b&b(a+b+c)\\1&c&c(a+b+c)\end{vmatrix}
= 0$$
The final step follows because the second and third column are linearly dependent.

Comment: Just realized this is what LutzL said to do