# $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a &bc \\ 1& b & ac\\ 1&c & ab \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a &a^2 \\ 1& b&b^2 \\ 1& b & c^2 \end{vmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Prove that  \begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & a &bc \\ 
>  1& b & ac\\ 
>  1&c  & ab
> \end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & a &a^2 \\ 
>  1&  b&b^2 \\ 
>  1& b & c^2
> \end{vmatrix}\\&=(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & a & a^2\\ 
>  0& 1 &b+a \\ 
>  0& 0 & 1
> \end{vmatrix}\\\\
> &=(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)\end{align}

I got the last two equalities but I did't get first two. I need help with first two

Comment: @DietrichBurde..sorry equality

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh..i need help with first two

Comment: I believe it should be $c$ instead of $b$ in the third row and second column.

Comment: I guest the (3,2) entry in the second matrix is $c$, not $b$.

Comment: @Itay4...no question is right

Comment: @C.Ding..no every thing is right

Comment: Why not compute directly? The dimension is just 3.

Comment: is there a possibility that Itay4 and C.Ding are right but the question is wrong?

Comment: If $a=c=0$ and $b=1$, then the first determinant is $0$ and the second one is $-1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra determinant reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806779/linear-algebra-determinant-reduction) which shows a different method to prove this question.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &bc \\ 
 1& b & ac\\ 
 1&c  & ab
\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &a^2 \\ 
 1&  b&b^2 \\ 
 1& c & c^2
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &bc \\ 
 0& b-a & ac-bc\\ 
 0&c-a  & ab-bc
\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &a^2 \\ 
 0&  b-a&b^2-a^2 \\ 
 0& c-a & c^2-a^2
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &bc \\ 
 0& 1& -c\\ 
 0&1  &-b
\end{vmatrix}&=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &a^2 \\ 
 0& 1&b+a \\ 
 0& 1 & c+a
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &bc \\ 
 0& 1& -c\\ 
 0&0  &c-b
\end{vmatrix}&=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a &a^2 \\ 
 0& 1&b+a \\ 
 0& 0& c-b
\end{vmatrix}\end{align}

Comment: -1: using the awful and misguided "working on both sides of the equality" technique that so often leads to error.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: thanks for recalling that subjectivity still rules.

Answer (score 0):

From the last column, we remove the common factor $abc$;

Then we multiply the first line by $a$, the second line by $b$ and the last line by $c$.